# On $\lambda(n)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Let $\lambda(n)$ be the Carmichael Lambda Function of $n$.

We know that for every $m$ there is the largest $n_m\in\Bbb N$ such that for every $n>n_m$ we have $\lambda(n)\neq m$ and $\lambda(n_m)=n$ holds?

Given $m$ what is a good bound on $n_m$?

Comment: You meant $\lambda(n_m)=m$?

Comment: It's certainly not true that the inverse image of any $m$ is non-empty (so $n_m$ may not exist).  For instance there is no $n$ such that $\lambda(n)=3$.  The set of values taken by $\lambda$ is not understood precisely, but it is known to grow more slowly than $x(\log x)^{-0.086}$, so most integers are *not* values of $\lambda$.

Comment: For a given $m$, it seems difficult to give a good bound, but there at least is *a* bound: $n_m \le \text{lcm}_{d\mid m} (\text{lcm}_{\lambda(p^r) = d} p^r)$.  The set of prime powers $p^r$ for a fixed $d$ is effectively bounded since it generally has at most two elements: $d+1$ and $q^{r+1}$ where $q^r$ is the power of the largest prime dividing $d$ (slightly different when $d$ is a power of $2$).